# Attempting to create a read only shared memory area with CreateFileMapping and custom DACL fails in OpenFileMapping

Tags: c++, c, windows, shared-memory

I have a client/server local process for which I wish to provide some content in a publicly **read-only** shared memory area.  I am able to successfully create the security descriptor and shared memory area on the server side, however when I try to access the shared memory area on the client side it fails with ACCESS_DENIED (5) *unless* the security descriptor grants write access to interactive users (GW) in addition to read (GR).  I'm trying to avoid granting write access to interactive users to prevent a rouge process from being able to trash the shared memory area.

The server side is designed to run as a windows service and use a global section but I've found that for the purpose of troubleshooting this issue it doesn't matter what it is running as.

Server Side:

```
// Error handling removed for brevity
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES attributes = { 0 };
ZeroMemory(&attributes, sizeof(attributes));
attributes.nLength = sizeof(attributes);
ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
    L"D:P(D;;GA;;;BG)(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)",
    SDDL_REVISION_1, &attributes.lpSecurityDescriptor, NULL);

DWORD cbMemShare = 1024;
m_hShareMem = CreateFileMappingW(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, &attributes, PAGE_READWRITE|SEC_COMMIT, 0, cbMemShare, L"MyMemShare");
```

Client side (as interactive user):

```
// succeeds if SD has (A;;GRGW;;;IU), fails on (A;;GR;;;IU)
HANDLE hShareMem = OpenFileMappingW(PAGE_READONLY, 0, L"MyMemShare");
if (hShareMem == NULL)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
}
```

Bottom line is I can't figure out a way to make this memory read accessible without it being write accessible.  Server should have read/write, client should have read.  I've researched this but haven't found anything definitive.

Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateFileMappingW()` and `OpenFileMappingW()`  use different sets of protection flag defines.

The flags supported by `CreateFileMappingW()` are listed in the [CreateFileMappingW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw) documentation:

> flProtect
>
> Specifies the page protection of the file mapping object. All mapped views of the object must be compatible with this protection.
>
> This parameter can be one of the following values.
>
> PAGE_EXECUTE_READ
>   PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
>   PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
>   PAGE_READONLY
>   PAGE_READWRITE
>   PAGE_WRITECOPY
>
> An application can specify one or more of the following attributes for the file mapping object by combining them with one of the preceding page protection values.
>
> SEC_COMMIT
>   SEC_IMAGE
>   SEC_IMAGE_NO_EXECUTE
>   SEC_LARGE_PAGES
>   SEC_NOCACHE
>   SEC_RESERVE
>   SEC_WRITECOMBINE

The flags supported by `OpenFileMappingW()` are listed in the [OpenFileMappingW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-openfilemappingw)) documentation:

> dwDesiredAccess
>
> The access to the file mapping object. This access is checked against any security descriptor on the target file mapping object. For a list of values, see [File Mapping Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping-security-and-access-rights).

Where the [File Mapping Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping-security-and-access-rights) documentation says:

> The following table lists the access rights that are specific to file-mapping objects.
>
> FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS
>   FILE_MAP_EXECUTE
>   FILE_MAP_READ
>   FILE_MAP_WRITE

When calling `OpenFileMappingW()`, you need to use `FILE_MAP_READ` instead of `PAGE_READONLY`.  If you look at the numeric values of `FILE_MAP_READ` and `PAGE_READONLY`:

winbase.h

```c
#define FILE_MAP_READ   4
#define FILE_MAP_WRITE  2
```

winnt.h

```c
#define PAGE_READONLY       0x02
```

As you can see, `FILE_MAP_READ` is 4 but `PAGE_READONLY` is 2, which is the same numeric value as `FILE_MAP_WRITE`.  As such, your client is actually requesting write access to the mapping, which is why the security descriptor needs to include write access.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I must have re-read the documentation 20 times but couldn't see the obvious.  Yes, I was requesting write access all along!